# Odd issue with filenames with special characters

Tags: apache

I'm having a very odd issue.

I have 2 servers and one of them isn't showing images/files with special characters on it. That's a Plesk/Apache server.

See here:

http://leita.gardplontur.is/pics/450/Ajuga%20reptans%20Multicolor%20-%20Dvergavör_GH.jpg

This one works just fine, but when i move it to the second server it's not displaying the file..

http://gard.verksmidjan.is/plontuleit/450/Ajuga%20reptans%20Multicolor%20-%20Dvergavör_GH.jpg

Any help on this issue is well appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not much really as i found very little on this issue on google. Not sure what i should be looking for...

Comment: did you try to set `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` on both servers in the apache conf?